# specific values in 2 cells on same row in different columns if

Tags: excel, vba

wht i want is if cell value in column A is 60 then cell value in the same row in column C must equal FF code below.

```
Sub column_check2()

Dim c As Range

Dim alastrow As Long

Dim clastrow As Long

alastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

clastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Range("A2:A3" & alastrow & ",C2:C3" & clastrow)


If Not c.Value = "60" And c.Value = "FF" Then

    MsgBox "error" & c.Address

End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Loop through one column, not both

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with the msgbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop through each value in `Column A` and check your criteria (*`Cell = 60`*). You can then adjust the value in `Column C` by using `Offset` to navigate 2 cells to the right from the current cell in the loop

---

```
Sub Looper()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")            'Update Sheet Name
Dim lr As Long, Target As Range

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each Target In ws.Range("A2:A" & lr)
    If Target = 60 Then
        Target.Offset(0, 2) = "FF"
    End If
Next Target

End Sub
```

---

***Even better***, consider the way you would likely do this manually. Filter `Column A` for your target value and then just modify the resultant cells in `Column C`. Recreating this in VBA results in a solution more efficient than a loop (*the larger the data set, the larger the efficiency gains*)

```
Sub Filter()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long: lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  ws.Range("A1:A" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=60               'Filter
  ws.Range("C2:C" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "FF"     'Apply Values
  ws.AutoFilterMode = False                                              'Remove Filter

End Sub
```